# Identify classical soundtrack of a steam engine video

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I am looking to find the name of the music used on this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/gwm95YFcTVQ?t=430) of a steam engine.

I used Google translate to translate the comments in hope of finding the name to no avail.

Comment: For future questions, here you can learn [how you can improve your question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721) 
and increase your chances for find the music you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from a piece called [*Orpheus in the Underworld*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLBWx_2y4R4), from Jacques Offenbach, you are looking for the "Can-can" part.